# Why does this module only have part of the registered functions available?

Tags: module, lua

[I've got this UTF-8 module for Lua](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alexander-yakushev/awesompd/master/utf8.lua).

The thing is that if `require()` it, only the first two functions (`charbytes` and `len`) are available. The rest is unavailable, despite being defined.

I tested this with a very simple script:

`utf8 = require("utf8")
print(utf8.len, utf8.sub)`

It returns: `function: 0xsomeaddress nil`. Why is that?

Comment: working fine for me. module code looks fine.

Comment: @Piglet I've located the issue to be that Lua 5.3 ships and `utf8` module by itself, and basically `require("utf8")` reloads that shipped module instead of my custom one.

Comment: Simply rename the file to something else, like my_utf8.lua

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lua 5.3 has an `utf8` module and it's already loaded, so `require("utf8")` actually doesn't do anything with the modules.

Comment: Not "higher priority" but "already loaded". If you "unload" (or never load in the first place) the built-in module the external one will work.

Comment: require avoids loading modules multiple times. so it acutally does not reload the built-in module. it will simply deny loading your module as utf8 is already loaded. see Modules section in the Lua ref for details.